# Export contact list in outlook 2007 to a pst file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export, contacts, pst

How do I export only the contact list from Outlook 2007 to a PST file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Office website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-contacts-to-another-computer-HA001105393.aspx):

- On the **File** menu, click **Import and Export**.

[image: Selecting import and export]

- Click **Export to a file**, and then click **Next**.

[image: Selecting export to a file]

- In the list, click **Personal Folder File (.pst)**, and then click **Next**.

[image: Selecting PST format]

- Click the **Contacts** folder. If the folder contains a subfolder that you want to include, select the **Include subfolders** check box, and then click **Next**.

[image: Choosing the contacts folder]

- Under **Save exported file as**, click **Browse**, and then specify a location, such as My Documents, and a name, such as **Contacts Backup**, for your backup file.
- If you back up a .pst file that you have backed up to before, click one of the following:

  - **Replace duplicates with items exported**
    Existing data will be overwritten with the information in the file that is being exported.
  - **Allow duplicate items to be created**
    Existing data will not be overwritten, and duplicate information will be added to the backup file.
  - **Do not export duplicate items**
    Existing data will be kept, and the duplicate information in the folder will not be copied to the backup file.
- Click **Finish**.